How can I pass components from server files to svelte pages with Svelte5?
I am writing a blog site using mdsvex and SvelteKit5. My current +page.server.ts file tried to pass the rendered component, but it is now a function and not an object (link to docs) and therefore I get an error saying:

Cannot stringify a function (data.component)

import { slugFromPath } from '$lib/slugFromPath';
import { error } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const load = async ({ params }) => {
    const modules = import.meta.glob(`/src/posts/*.{md,svx,svelte.md}`);

    let match: { path?: string; resolver?: App.MdsvexResolver } = {};
    for (const [path, resolver] of Object.entries(modules)) {
        if (slugFromPath(path) === params.slug) {
            match = { path, resolver: resolver as unknown as App.MdsvexResolver };
            break;
        }
    }

    console.log(params.slug)

    const post = await match?.resolver?.();


    if (!post || !post.metadata.published) {
        throw error(404); // Couldn't resolve the post
    }

    return {
        component: post.default,
        frontmatter: post.metadata
    };
};

My +page.svelte file is as follows:
<script lang="ts">

    import type { SvelteComponentTyped } from 'svelte';

    import PageHead from '$lib/components/PageHead.svelte';
    import ArticleTitle from '$lib/components/ArticleTitle.svelte';
    import ArticleMeta from '$lib/components/ArticleMeta.svelte';

    let {data} = $props();
    let component = $state(data.component);
</script>

<PageHead title={data.frontmatter.title} description={data.frontmatter.description} />
<ArticleTitle title={data.frontmatter.title} />
<ArticleMeta author={data.frontmatter.author} date={data.frontmatter.date} />

<svelte:component this={component} />

I can't find a way to pass the component as an object so that it can be assigned to the svelte:component tag. Is there a way of doing this in Svelte5?

Regular components can still be passed, not sure what the problem/difference is. Are you on the latest versions? (Kit >= 2.5.5, Svelte >= 5.0.0-next.90)

@brunnerh Not that I can get to work. I am on the latest version for both. In the breaking changes for Svelte5 that I linked, it says "Components are no longer classes" so I'm struggling to understand what I'm meant to do in this situation when they're now represented as functions.

The component should never cross the wire, so it should not be a problem. Are you using a server load rather than a universal one? The change between classes and functions should not mean much, neither are serializable by default.

Yes thanks! That's fixed it. I didn't know there was a difference between page.ts and page.server.ts and as I wanted SSR I thought I'd have to use page.server.ts.

Components can only be returned from universal load functions which run separately on the server and the client. This does not work for server load functions which serialize their returned data to pass over the network.
Docs on load function output:

A universal load function can return an object containing any
values, including things like custom classes and component
constructors.
A server load function must return data that can be serialized with
devalue — anything that can
be represented as JSON plus things like BigInt, Date, Map, Set
and RegExp, or repeated/cyclical references — so that it can be
transported over the network. Your data can include
promises, in which case it will be
streamed to browsers.

